# How can I convert BASE64 to Image in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter Code:

```
$filedata = explode(',', $this->input->post('lostimage1'));
$pos  = strpos($this->input->post('lostimage1'), ';');
$type = explode(':', substr($this->input->post('lostimage1'), 0, $pos))[1];
$type = '.'.$type;
$type = str_replace('image/', '', $type);
$img1 = $img['img'].''.$type;
write_file('./uploads/'.$data['pet_hidenum'].'/'.$img1, $filedata[1]);
```

My code is working fine. when I am downloading the image from the server and opening it image in paint or chrome then it displaying error invalid bitmap How can I resolve this error?

Comment: well, tried the solutions in [php.net regarding base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) yet? -- especially **tobias at silverxnet dot de** one. can't try it yet..

Comment: No I not tried it. But why it not working please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode(imagejpeg($image)).'" />';
```

See this post for more information on this https://delboy1978uk.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/outputting-images-as-base64-encoded-strings/